# How to set background to overlay text in next js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, next.js, sass

I am creating an image element with overlay text. Here is my `jsx` code

```
<div className={styles.img}>
    <img src={src} alt="" />
    <p>{`(${size})`}</p>        
</div>
```

and here is `sass`

```
.img {
    min-width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    img {
        height: 90px;
        box-shadow: orangered 0 0 5px;
    }
    p {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: .8rem;
        margin-top: - 1.6rem;
        // max-width: 120px;
        // z-index: 100;
        background-color: #0070f3;
    }
}
```

I get result as shown in following image. The background of `p` tag is visible only outside the `img` and not over the `img`.

[image]

Checkout this issue live [here](https://get-youtube-thumbnail.vercel.app/).

How do I show the background for overlay text on image so that it is readable?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it did not work. Also, I should not be required to add z-index. I just added to test to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `position` to something other than the default value (static) in order to use `z-index`. Here's an example with `position: relative`.

```css
p
{
background: #0cf;
margin-top: -1.6rem;
z-index: 100;
}

p.positioned
{
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x80"/>
<p>Test without positioning</p>

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x80"/>
<p class="positioned">Test with positioning</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comment by @Devid.

Just to clarify, the `position: relative` should be added on the `p` tag. Adding `position: relative` to the container div does not make any difference.